# MySQL encrypt() with salt accepts random characters after password

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have a table with usernames and encrypted passwords.

The passwords are encrypted by means of MySQL encrypt() together with a salt (the first two characters of the password).

Recently I've noticed that MySQL accepts passwords even if they contain random characters at the end.

Suppose we have this kind of table:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(11,    'ricardomontalban', ENCRYPT(11111111,11));
```

And now I query for my user:

```
-- The following shows the appropriate response --
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "ricardomontalban" AND password = ENCRYPT(11111111,11);

-- HOWEVER, the following query also shows a result, even with random characters appended!!! --
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "ricardomontalban" AND password = ENCRYPT("11111111-55669964s5465sqsfqsdf",11);

-- No problem with prepended random characters though --
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "ricardomontalban" AND password = ENCRYPT("smlkfjmlsdkfjslqf-11111111",11);
```

I've created an SQL Fiddle to show this example in real time:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/898d5/9

What am I doing wrong? Should I even be using this encryption method?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt):

> ENCRYPT() ignores all but the first eight characters of str, at least on some systems. This behavior is determined by the implementation of the underlying crypt() system call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this imply that passwords should only be allowed to be 8 characters long? Would you suggest not using this encryption method?

Comment: don't use encrypt for passwords. it's a useless hash these days. if you want security, then use a strong hash (md5, sha1) as a STARTING point, and seriously consider a hash dedicated to pw protection, like bcrypt. md5/sha1 are better than nothing, but they're so light on computational requirements they're getting far too easy to brute force.

Comment: Thanks. Bcrypt it is, then. Do you know of any good reference to get started with bcrypt?

Comment: mysql doesn't have bcrypt built-in, so it'll depend on your client-side programming language. any crypto library worth its salt (hah!) should have it available somewhere.

Comment: I'm using a traditional PHP/MySQL setup. I have found some basic references:
http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igLvmIXkQ4Q

Comment: http://php.net/crypt  there's some bcrypt stuff down in the comments on that page.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other questions:

Using the first two (or any) characters from the password as the salt is also wrong.   The idea of the salt is to provide some randomness to the encrypted passwords so that users who have the same password will have different hashes.

Use an established encryption library (such as bcrypt) for whatever programming language you are using.